# Find holes in an enumeration in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this

```
1400a_comp      49472                       2868636.1026583919660    GOOD      
1400a_comp      49473                       2868647.1026579919650    GOOD      
1400a_comp      49474                       2868659.1026575919639    GOOD      
1400a_comp      49475                       2868670.1026571919627    GOOD      
1400a_comp      49476                       2868682.1026567819614    GOOD      
1400a_comp      49477                       2868693.1026563819603    GOOD
```

I want to search the file for instances where the second field does not increment by one  and print the line number

Comment: Would have been helpful to provide an example that actually demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
awk '$2!=last+1{print NR}{last=$2}' filename
```

This compares the second field to the last value and prints if equal to one more; then the second field of this line is saved for the next comparison.  This will always display the first line (q.e.d.).

Answer (score 5):

I like the solution by @Arcege but it outputs the first line no matter what.  If you want to suppress the fist line, you can use a slight modification to his solution as

```
awk 'NR != 1 && $2!=last+1{print}{last=$2}' filename
```